# Google Meet: is the meeting nickname available via the audit log API?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm entering a meeting nickname (`Test Meeting`) for a Google Meet meeting.

However, I'm not able to find the meeting nickname in the response from the audit log API.  Is there another API where this information is available?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chatting with Google Support, there is no way currently to access the Google Meet meeting nickname via the audit log API.