# Tracking nicknamed Meets attendance

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api, google-meet

In a Google Education (Classroom) context, we are trying to get (via an API) the attendance for the meets generated by a certain nickname (specifically for the ones generated by the google classroom courses).
We are able to get Meet statistics using the activities.list but there we have to provide a meet_code and we are not finding the way to get the stats for all of the Meets related to a nickname (or at least, identify all of the meet codes related to this nickname so that we can search afterwards the stats one by one).
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [I think this is not possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63236135/11551468)

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*This isn't yet possible to do.*

#### More Information:

Meet nicknames are currently not exposed to the API, so obtaining call information based on a nickname isn't possible.

#### Feature Request:

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services. As it happens, there is already a feature request for this, which you can view here:

- [Add alias code to Meet Audit Activity Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/162255868)

Google has responded to this feature request, but I suggest that you indicate your desire for this to be implemented by hitting the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned page, which lets Google prioritise which feature requests should be implemented sooner.

#### Related Questions:

- [Google Meet: is the meeting nickname available via the audit log API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63236135/11551468)